# Как можно инициализировать структуру с размещением по адресу с помощью атрибута

Tags: c

Есть структура:

```
    typedef struct DIO{
       unionDio DIO00;
       _DIO_MIN DIO_MIN[63];  
       _DIO_MID DIO_MID[32];       
       _DIO_MAX DIO_MAX[4];        
       float    GLOB[8192];
       uint16_t ASUIO[32768];
       uint8_t  LOCALL[32768];
       float    STATDATA[32768];
       char     ERRORS[80];
       int      READYINPUT;
} _SysMem;
```

Разместил ее:

```
_SysMem SYSMEM __attribute__((section(".DIO")));
```

Хочу чтобы структура была инициализированная нулями.

пытаюсь написать вот так

```
_SysMem SYSMEM = {0} __attribute__((section(".DIO")));
```

получаю ошибку

Comment: дык, а наоборот не работает: `_SysMem SYSMEM __attribute__((section(".DIO"))) = {0};`... и какая ошибка? определяешь в глобальной области видимости?

Comment: `... = (struct DIO) { 0 };`